# Why does model.find() only look for documents within certain collections inside my database?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am using a tutorial to learn how to use GraphQL and mongoose. I was wondering why when I call .find() on my Post model in my resolver it seems to only return me documents inside collection called 'posts'. If I delete 'posts' collection and change name but copy over exact same documents, my query will return me empty object [].

This is my file containing type definitions

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');

module.exports = gql`
    type Post {
        id: ID!
        body: String!
        createdAt: String!
        username: String!
    }
    type User{
        id: ID!
        email: String!
        token: String!
        username: String!
        createdAt: String!
    }
    input RegisterInput{
        username: String!
        password: String!
        confirmPassword: String!
        email: String!
    }
    type Query { 
        getPosts: [Post] #getPosts query
    }
    type Mutation{
        register(registerInput: RegisterInput): User!
    }
`;
```

this is my file that generates the model for posts

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
    body: String,
    username: String,
    createdAt: String,
    comments: [
        {
            body: String,
            username: String,
            createDate: String
        }
    ],
    likes: [
        {
            username: String,
            createDate: String
        }
    ],
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    }
})

module.exports = model('Post', postSchema);
```

this is my resolver for the previously defined getPost query

```
const Post = require('../../models/Post');

module.exports = {
    Query: { 
        async getPosts(){ //resolver for getPosts query
            try{
                const post = await Post.find(); //finds all
                return post; 
            } catch(err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out its because when I created a model using model() the first argument is the collection that the model is designed for.